# How to solve warnings from GDB?

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting, debugging, debug, gdb

I need help about debugging GIMP 2.10.10

O.S. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

GDB Version (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git

I get this message from GDB when i try to generate a backtrace inside flatpak sandbox

```
Starting program: /app/bin/gimp 
warning: File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so
line to your configuration file "/home/user/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/user/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
```

i restart terminal and i try:

```
gdb add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so
```

> add-auto-load-safe-path: No such file or directory.
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so: No such file or directory.

Then i use:

```
gdb set auto-load safe-path /
```

> warning: set: No such file or directory.
>
> /home/user/auto-load: No such file or directory.

Also i try:

```
gdb -q -iex "set auto-load safe-path /home/user/gdb" ./gdb
```

> ./gdb: No such file or directory.

Please help me notice what i'm doing wrong

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding those lines to your `~/.gdbinit` file instead of trying to run them from the command line?

Comment: @Terrance Ok i have added `add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so` and `set auto-load safe-path /` to my `~/.gdbinit` i only get one warning: warning: `Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.`

Comment: Not really sure about that one.  The closest I can find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364781/gdb-debugging-warnings?rq=1

Comment: @Terrance let me check the info, thanks for the help

Comment: I can't comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364781/gdb-debugging-warnings?rq=1) i have added `set debug libthread-db 1` to my `~/.gdbinit` the command line returning: `Trying host libthread_db library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1.
td_ta_new failed: application not linked with libthread
thread_db_load_search returning 0`

Comment: It may sound weird but I got same message when the machine was low on memory.

Comment: Check this [Loading .gdbinit from current directory fails with “auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595417/loading-gdbinit-from-current-directory-fails-with-auto-loading-has-been-declin)